# Matching jobs to applicants

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, matching

I have a big database of jobs, each job has numerical and non numerical attributes like(position,field,salary, needed experience...)
and applicants to jobs that determine some attributes like(age, expected salary...)

I want to create an application that do automatic matching between the jobs and the appropriate candidates**What is the best Algorithm to apply (data mining or artificial intelligence) to implement this app.**

thx for your replies

Comment: What are the requirements? Do you want to find jobs to as many applicants as possible? Do you want to find for the jobs the best candidates? Do you have reward for each position and you want to maximize the sum reward?

Comment: Another thing to ask: does your database have any data on "good" and "bad" matches from previous jobs? If it doesn't, then you can't really employ (no pun intended) an AI algorithm to determine which candidate is good and which one is not good, because there is no such data to train the algorithm on.

Comment: I want the candidate to find the jobs that fit to him , it's like sending emails with approplirate jobs

Comment: I wish companies would use good algorithms for this, I receive terrible ones :)

Comment: @Mariya, so do you have historical data showing good and bad matches between the job postings and the candidates? You can't just create an algorithm that will automatically figure it out, but you can teach one to do so if you have previous data which depicts good/bad matches.

Comment: If you have the attributes of the applicants matching should be *trivial*. But you usually only have the CV and have to extract the attributes. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Lirik No at first I've only the jobs I've nothing else I guess I need to cluster or something like that

Comment: @yi_H yes I have to extract them but I a asking about the jobs data mining and the match algorithm

Comment: @Mariya you need data on previously identified good candidates for a specific job and bad candidates for the same job. Having both will allow you to train a machine learning algorithm...

Comment: @Lirik Thank you for your suggestion :) 

any other idea ??

Comment: @Mariya, that's the main thing. Once you get your data, then it's only a matter of trying out some different algorithms...

Comment: should we apply a  fuzzy clustering applied to jobs thus we can have different sets of jobs which present a kind of similarity ???

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you want is a recommendation algorithm, not matching algorithm.

There is not best recommendation algorithm which work for all cases. You should look into several algorihms and select which suits best for your situation. I recommend you to look at [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) which implements lots of such recommendation algorithms and is an open-source library.